# How to interpret the metrics of Locust?

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I found no detail about the **Number of users to simulate** and **Hatch rate** in the locust documentation.

What is the relation between the two parameters?

If I have 20 clients, of each will post 1000 requests/second to the server, how should I set the two parameters to test the server?

Answer (score 15):

"Hatch rate" is how quickly you want to spawn the users.

Example:

```
"Number of users to simulate" = 20

"Hatch rate" (user spawned / second) = 2
```

When you start the load test with this configuration, locust will spawn 2 new users for every second until it fulfils the total number of users to simulate (which is 20 in this case). After 10 seconds, you will have a swarm of 20 simulated users.

To control the no. of request per second, you will need to set the [max_wait](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/writing-a-locustfile.html#the-min-wait-and-max-wait-attributes) accordingly.